# Definition of "almost inclusion" and "almost in"

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, notation, set-theory

Is there in measure theory/topology the concept of "almost inclusion"?

**Possible definition:**
*In a measurable space $(X,\mu)$ one set $A$ is almost included in another set $B$ if $A$ is included in $B$ to less than a finite number of zero-measure points.*

Example:

$$A=\{-1\}\cup[2,3]\text{ and }B=[1,4]\;\Rightarrow\;A\;\dot\subset \;B$$

Where $\dot\subset$ is the symbol of almost inclusion (I don't know if that is used, but there is the inclusion symbol and a dot that reminds me of the fact that it is less than a finite number of zero-measure sets, so I used it)

If this definition already exists, what are the analogous symbols to indicate: $A\subset B$ and $a\in A$ (the second symbol should be a sort of "almost in")

I state that I searched online if it existed, but I didn't find anything, even if they seem to me quite usable definitions.

Comment: I’ve often heard “essentially” used in similar situations. E.g., $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ are “essentially disjoint”. So if I were to invent a term for your question, I would probably say that $B$ essentially contains $A$ (or variations on that) if $A\setminus B$ has measure zero.

Comment: In a probability space context, you might say pretty much the same thing as something like "event $A$ almost surely implies event $B$".

Comment: @Milten I changed the ranges otherwise it could be confused with the concept of equals almost everywhere

Comment: I don’t know what you would mean by your “almost $a\in A$” though. Do you have a precise definition in mind? Perhaps something like $a$ is in the closure of $A$? Or $dist(a,A)=0$ if it’s a metric space?

Comment: @Milten One possibility is $\{a\} \setminus A$ being null (ie "almost $\{a\} \subset A$), which is equivalent to $a \in A$ or $\mu(\{a\}) = 0$. Of course if $(X, \mu)$ is such that the measure of finite sets is $0$ then this is a trivial condition.